# Selenium Webscraping JavaScript elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I am trying to use selenium and PhantomJS to scrape some of the elements produced by JavaScript.

My Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from collections import OrderedDict
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/profile_report?global_id=01290021&starttab=landuserestrictions')

driver.find_element_by_id('sitefacdocsTab').click()
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

After the click action I still get the old page data, not the new data which is given by jQuery.

Comment: But there is no click in the script, is it?

Comment: I didn't understand your question..

Comment: Are you fine with a solution that doesn't use Selenium to get the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `requests`

Open Developer tools > Network > XHR tab in your browser. Then, click on the `Site/Facility Docs` tab. You'll see an AJAX request in the XHR tab. The request is sent to [this site](http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/profile_report_include?global_id=01290021&ou_id=&site_id=&tabname=sitefacdocs&orderby=&schorderby=&comporderby=&rand=0.07839738919075079&_=1521609095041) to get the tab data.

You can scrape anything you want from that tab by simply using `requests` module.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/profile_report_include?global_id=01290021&ou_id=&site_id=&tabname=sitefacdocs&orderby=&schorderby=&comporderby=&rand=0.07839738919075079&_=1521609095041')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# And to check whether we've got the correct data:
table = soup.find('table', class_='display-v4-default')
print(table.find('a', target='_documents').text)
# Soil Management Plan Implementation Report, Public Market Infrastructure Relocation, Phase 1-B Infrastructure Area
```

---

## Using `Selenium`

When you want to wait for a page to load, you should **never** use `time.sleep()`. You should use [**Eplicit Waits**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead. After using that, you can get the whole tab content using the `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` property.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/profile_report?global_id=01290021&starttab=landuserestrictions')

driver.find_element_by_id('sitefacdocsTab').click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'docdatediv')))

html = driver.find_element_by_id('sitefacdocs').get_attribute('innerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', class_='display-v4-default')
print(table.find('a', target='_documents').text)
# Soil Management Plan Implementation Report, Public Market Infrastructure Relocation, Phase 1-B Infrastructure Area
```

**Additional info:**

The element with `id="docdatediv"` is the `div` tag that contains date range filter. I've used it as it is not present on the first tab, but is present on the tab you want. You can use any such element for the `WebDriverWait`.

And, the element with `id="sitefacdocs"` is the `div` tag which contains the entire tab contents (i.e. the date filter and all the tables below). So, your `soup` object will have all those things to scrape.

Comment: What an excellent answer! Another reminder that the soluion we think of as appropriate may not be the optimal solution at all.

Comment: I agree with the solution but if i want to scrape another tab Activities, i couldnt see any element change which is unique in that tab. so what do in that case?

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar, you can use the `id` of any element in that tab since the `id` is always unqiue. For the `Activities` tab, you can use `(By.ID, 'activities')`

Comment: There are many things you can use for `expected_conditions`. Just go through the docs of explicit wait I've linked above. To tell you everything about them is too broad and out of scope of this question. I'm sure this solution will solve your problem for all tabs (using `id`'s or even different `class`es).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar yes i can use the first method and works, it wont work dynamically, since the page i am scraping changes according to particular parameter called global_id. plus for each tab it produces new url in XHR , so any how i have to perform clicks.

Comment: *but how can i get this url from*  - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar yes second method works for all tabs, but i am not able to detect changes in each tab, and for activities tab , it is not identifying  by the id activities.

Comment: Are you changing the id in the find element line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167354/discussion-between-sriram-arvind-lakshmanakumar-and-keyur-potdar).